# when a function convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence, power-series

How could I find the the convergence field for the given function:

$$f_n(x)=\frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x^{2n}}$$

As we know from normal functions it converges when $n-1<2n$ but that's always trues which isn't the correct answer

Comment: @clark_smith1 did you mean convergence of series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)$ ?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin yes

Comment: @DigAmma it converges too for x=-2

Comment: any help? I found It doesn't converge when x=1 or x=-1...

Comment: Is the answer$ \mathbb{R} \setminus\left \{ 1,-1 \right \}$

Comment: @DigAmma yes it is

Comment: @DigAmma any updates?